# Is there a supported method for exporting Drools rules to XML

Tags: drools

I am looking for a way to export rules to XML.
I read about DRLDumper, but I'm not sure if it's deprecated or not.
Is this the way to go? are there any alternative?

Thanks,
Eliezer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml exporter is quite old and deprecated. Can you please clarify why do you want to export to xml? What is the business/technical requirement to do that?

Comment: W'ere looking for a way to export the rules of our system to a an external system, so that external system will be able to make sure the parameters it sends, will comply with our rules

Comment: It doesn't have to be XML. I thought about it because of the DRLDumper. XSD or JSON Schema are preferable alternatives. I was hoping to find something ready and not build this from scratch.

Comment: As far as i am aware there is nothing like that yet, which makes me think that a json schema generator for rules might be a great community contribution. I recommend you to create an issue in github so we can discuss with the community how that can be achieved